# Entity Framework Core SQLite version

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core v2.2.1 for SQLite and just made a new migration, where I renamed a field in the table.

Migration code looks like

```
migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
    name: "OldColumnName",
    table: "Table",
    newName: "NewColumnName");
```

It creates following SQL when I apply migration:

```
ALTER TABLE "Table" RENAME COLUMN "OldColumnName" TO "NewColumnName";
```

Staring with SQLite 3.25 it is supported https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

```
Enhancements the ALTER TABLE command:

    Add support for renaming columns within a table using ALTER TABLE table RENAME COLUMN oldname TO newname.
    Fix table rename feature so that it also updates references to the renamed table in triggers and views.
```

But in EF Core I receive an exception:

```
Error while executing SQL query on database 'MyDatabase': near "COLUMN": syntax error
```

Sounds like it uses old version of SQLite. How can check which version does EF Core use?

EDIT: I found a workaround, but actually my question is "how do I know which version of SQLite am I currently using?".

Answer (score 2):

Renaming column for sqlite db in ef core is limited and not supported you can find official limitation lists [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations)

there is a bug report for this problem that you can find it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13341)
and there is a workaround for this issue in [here](https://elanderson.net/2017/04/entity-framework-core-with-sqlite-migration-limitations/)

Comment: I believe the proper workaround for this specific case (renaming a column) is using native SQLite library as described here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13341#issuecomment-427895114, but generally the SQLiteStudio does the trick.